# C strcpy causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct occurrenceType Occurrence;

struct occurrenceType {
char* line;
int lineNumber;
int wordNumber;
Occurrence *next;
```

};

That I'm attempting to create a linked list with like this:

```
inFile=fopen(argv[1],"r");
while(fgets(line,100,inFile)!=NULL) {
    if(strstr(line,argv[2])!='\0') {
            strcpy((*occur).line,line);
                (*occur).lineNumber=count;
                (*occur).next=(Occurrence*)malloc(sizeof(Occurrence));
                occur=(*occur).next;
        lineCount++;
    }
    count++;
}
```

The program is supposed to read lines of a program and search for a string specified in the command line.  When a match is found, an occurrence is added to the linked list.  Everything works correctly except for the 'line' field of the struct.  When using strcpy to populate it, a segmentation fault occurs, but

```
(*occur).line=line;
```

is not a viable option because the line pointer changes throughout the program.  Can anyone suggest an alternate way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: need to allocate `line` first before writing into it

Comment: @amdixon how would I correctly do that? I tried it before to no avail.

Comment: BTW, `occur->lineNumber` and `occur->next` are the more common way to write field references through a pointer, as opposed to `(*occur).lineNumber` and `(*occur).next`.

Comment: Also, since you use `malloc()`, your last list element won't be initialized to any meaningful state.  You probably want to explicitly initialize `occur->next = NULL` and maybe other fields after the line that says `occur = (*occur).next;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the line field or make it an actual character buffer.

If you're going to allocate, add this line just above the strcpy in the block:

```
    occur->line = calloc( 1, 100 );
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want to only allocate as much as the line needs.  The non-standard but quite common `strdup()` does just this.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not sure if he wants to keep the entire line he read or just the string he found. His code snippet doesn't suggest that fact, except that he's reading a string up to 100 bytes and then trying to save it off. I would further suggest to the author that he work on some issues to make the code more flexible, such as not using hardcoded sizes, @Joe Z's comment about condensing data storage, etc.

Comment: `strcpy(occur->line, line)` will stop at the ASCII NUL at the end, so there's no point in allocating more than `strlen(line) + 1` bytes, is there?

Comment: Ah, misread the details in your comment. Yes I agree with you on that point.